# Displaying console output?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am currently creating a customer application for a local company. I have a datagridview linked to the customers table, and I am trying to link it up so that updates, inserts and deletions are handled correctly. I am very new to c# so I am starting with the basics (like about 2 days ago I knew nothing - I know vb.net, Java and several other languages though..).

Anywho from what I understand anything output through Debug.WriteLine should only appear when in debug mode (common sense really) but anything output through Concole.WriteLine should appear whether or not in debug mode. However I have checked the immediate and output windows and nothing is being output when in normal mode. Does anyone have any idea why this is??

Edit: I have event handlers for clicking a cell - it should output CellClicked and set the gridview to invisible when a cell is clicked. The latter works whichever mode I am in, but CellClicked is only output in debug mode. I am using Console.WriteLine("CellClicked").

Edit: Seems I may have solved it - I just set the output to Console Application in the project settings pages. It now opens a command line window as well as a windows form, but I can change the output back again when I compile for distribution. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` outputs to the **console window** in the case of a console app *only*.

You are probably looking for `Trace.WriteLine()`.

Comment: Tracing is apparently a form of debugging - its not debugging I want to do.. using debug mode adds to the amount of time it takes to load the app (at least I cant see it reducing the time..) so I want to avoid using debug mode as much as possible. I want to output the odd statement now and then to check it is reaching specific points at the correct times, without using debug mode.

Comment: You can enable and disable tracing. Your app does not need to be in debug mode to do it.

Comment: @ClarkeyBoy:  What your are describing is EXACTLY what tracing is.  You don't have to have the app in debug mode to enable tracing...

Answer (score 3):

Getting the output of Console.Write/Line() written to the Visual Studio Output window is a feature of the Visual Studio Hosting process.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.  This will not work if you run your app without a debugger, the hosting process isn't being used.

Using Console.WriteLine for debugging isn't the greatest solution.  That code will still run in your Release build and take time formatting the output string.  And prevent the JIT optimizer from doing a good job generating the most efficient machine code.  Output will fall in the bit bucket, nothing to actually write it to.

And it is unnecessary, the debugger gives you much better tools to find out what is going on in your program.  Take some time to familiarize yourself with its capabilities.  If you want to find out if an event handler runs, just set a breakpoint.  Such a breakpoint can even trace output without actually breaking.  Right-click the red dot, click "When hit" and use the "Print message" option.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll like the tracing infrastructure a lot better than Console.WriteLine. Tracing gives you many different options for where the trace messages can go, as well as being able to turn them on or off.  You can also set different levels of tracing output so that you can adjust how much logging actually gets done.  The built in tracing in .NET is very flexible, and is well worth the investment to learn.

Here are a couple of references to help you get started:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228993.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228984.aspx
- http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0409081

HTH!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You could go to Tools | Options | Look for Debugging, General, Choose the Redirect all Output Window text to the immediate window, or try to log the console-intended output to a file and view it there instead.